# Add method to Constructor function that manipulates an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, constructor, prototype

I am attempting to create a simple program for practice that has a `Store` constructor which takes in an `inventoryList` array, an `InventoryItem` constructor that creates an object of each item to be stored within the `inventoryList` array. I want to add a method to the `InventoryItem` list that will take a number and add it to each item within the list. Below is my code:

```
var Store = function(inventory){
    this.inventory = inventory;
}

var InventoryItem = function(cost, color, size){
    this.cost = cost;
    this.color = color;
    this.size = size;
}

//create each inventory item as an object

var lamp = new InventoryItem(40.00, 'blue', 'small');
var throwPillow  = new InventoryItem(25.00, 'yellow', 'medium');
var sconce = new InventoryItem( 18.00, 'gold', 'large');
var candles = new InventoryItem(10.00, 'white', 'small');
var curtains = new InventoryItem(30.00, 'purple', 'large');

//store inventory items into an inventory object

var inventorylist = [lamp, throwPillow, sconce, candles, curtains];

// add number of items to each item

InventoryItem.prototype.howMany = function(num){
    function addCount(inventorylist){
        for(var i = 0; i < inventorylist.length; i++){
            inventorylist[i].howMany = num;
        }
    }
}

//store inventory within a store
var deannaStore = new Store(inventorylist);
var dionStore = new Store(inventorylist);
var mikeStore = new Store(inventorylist);
```

I am running into an issue when I attempt add a number to an item within the list
example: `dionStore.howMany(15)`

this gives me the error: `Uncaught TypeError: dionStore.howMany is not a function`

Any help would be greatly appreciated preferably with a detailed explanation of why this doesn't work.

Comment: `InventoryItem.prototype.howMany` should be `Store.prototype.howMany`

Comment: Why would it be on the Store prototype instead of Inventory Item if I am trying to add a count to each item? This also still produces the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the method `howMany` is defined for `InventoryItem` objects, but you try to call it to `dionStore` object which is a `Store`.

Can you please describe what you want to achieve?

**EDIT1 :**

Maybe add the `howMany` method to `Store`, like **Lashane** mentions,  which will create a `quantity` property to each `InvetoryItem` in its array

```
Store.prototype.howMany = function(num){
    function addCount(inventorylist){
        for(var i = 0; i < inventorylist.length; i++){
            inventorylist[i].quantity = num;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2 :**

In this case you will need a method in `InventoryItem` to set the quantity and another in `Store` to return the total quantity

```
Store.prototype.howMany = function(){
    var totalQuantity = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < inventorylist.length; i++){
        var item = inventorylist[i];

        if (item.hasOwnProperty('quantity')) {
            totalQuantity += item.quantity;
        }
    }

    return totalQuantity;
}

InventoryItem.prototype.addQuantity = function(quantity) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty('quantity')) {
        this.quantity += quantity;
    } else {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

```js
var Store = function(inventory) {
  this.inventory = inventory;
}

Store.prototype.howMany = function() {
  var totalQuantity = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < inventorylist.length; i++) {
    var item = inventorylist[i];

    if (item.hasOwnProperty('quantity')) {
      totalQuantity += item.quantity;
    }
  }

  return totalQuantity;
}

var InventoryItem = function(cost, color, size) {
  this.cost = cost;
  this.color = color;
  this.size = size;
}

InventoryItem.prototype.addQuantity = function(qunatity) {
  if (this.hasOwnProperty('quantity')) {
    this.quantity += qunatity;
  } else {
    this.quantity = qunatity;
  }
}


//create each inventory item as an object

var lamp = new InventoryItem(40.00, 'blue', 'small');
var throwPillow = new InventoryItem(25.00, 'yellow', 'medium');
var sconce = new InventoryItem(18.00, 'gold', 'large');
var candles = new InventoryItem(10.00, 'white', 'small');
var curtains = new InventoryItem(30.00, 'purple', 'large');

//store inventory items into an inventory object

var inventorylist = [lamp, throwPillow, sconce, candles, curtains];

lamp.addQuantity(1);
throwPillow.addQuantity(2);
sconce.addQuantity(3);
candles.addQuantity(4);
curtains.addQuantity(5);

lamp.addQuantity(1);

//store inventory within a store
var deannaStore = new Store(inventorylist);
var dionStore = new Store(inventorylist);
var mikeStore = new Store(inventorylist);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'dionStore.howMany() = ' + dionStore.howMany();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I want to be able to add a specific amount to each item within the inventoryList so that if called it would return how many of each item is in each store.

Comment: when I call `deannaStore.howMany(15)` I get 0 returned. It should store 15 as the quantity of each item within the list

Comment: You have to set the amount before you call howmany. See the updated example

Answer (score 0):

Your prototype defines a function and does nothing.  And it is on the wrong prototype.  Are you looking for this?

```
Store.prototype.howMany = function(num){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < this.inventory.length; i++){
        this.inventory[i].howMany = num;
    }
}
```